# How to disable right click menu in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

How can I disable the right click menu in html?

Please don't say its unprofessional, I am developing a public touch screen display for a museum.

I have already disabled text selection but if you touch and hold it brings the right click menu- very unprofessional :D

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me try this one: google > "javascript disable right click" > choose one out of hundred thousands of results? :)

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Are you talking about the regular right-click on a desktop?

Comment: @Mjh I have alredy tried that but it does not work :(

Comment: `It does not work` is the worst kind of answer you can give anyone. "Hello doctor, it hurts" - that's how useful it is.

Comment: What's the operating system on the device that you are trying to disable. Perhaps your title 'disable right-click' should be changed.

Comment: You tried to search for it but couldn't find anything? I don't believe that for a second.

Comment: @Mjh I know thats my problem. The answer below works fine.

Comment: If you're worried about professionality I'd consider making a native app for the touch device instead

Comment: [Results to this question from google](https://www.google.ie/search?q=%22javascript+disable+right+click%22&oq=%22javascript+disable+right+click%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.519j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @DavidG I dint say that. I said it did not work. The answer below works fine.

Comment: The answer below is on almost every link if you search for it on Google though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan A good idea, but I don't have any experience in app development. And C# has an internet explorer class which I use for a custom browser.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan possably I made a dogy copy and paste then. Anyway it works now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming this for a web app...

I also had to do this and used Javascript

```
 document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```

Should do the trick
Thanks

Comment: That's not jQuery